# Ocaml match fails

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

```
type ide = string;;
type integer = int;;

(*Eccezioni*)
exception WrongMatchException;;
exception EmptyEnvException;;
exception TypeErrorException;;
exception UnboundRecordException;;
exception OutOfBoundException;;

type exp =
    | Ide of ide (*Identificatore*)
    | Int of int (*Valori Interi*)
    | Bool of bool (*Valori Booleani, true=1, false=0*)
    | Add of exp * exp (*Operatori Matematici*)
    | Sub of exp * exp
    | Mul of exp * exp
    | Eq of exp * exp
    | Leq of exp * exp
    | And of exp * exp (*Operatori Logici*)
    | Or of exp * exp
    | Not of exp
    | Function of ide * ide * exp (*Funzione con un parametro, non ricorsiva*)
    | IfThenElse of exp * exp * exp (*Classico If Then Else *)
    | LetIn of ide * exp * exp (*Blocco Let*)
    | FunApply of ide * exp (*Applicazione funzionale Ide(E)*)
    | Tupla of ide * elts (*Espressione Tupla*)
    | GetIndex of elts * exp (*Accesso Elemento Tupla*)
    | GetFirstN of elts * exp (* Seleziona elementi Tupla*)
    | TupleEquals of elts * elts (*Confronto tra tuple*)
    | Map of ide * exp (*Applica funzione ad elementi tupla*)
    | ListaE of elts
and
(*Elementi di una tupla*)
    elts = Elemento of exp | Lista of exp list
;;

    (* the empty environment *)
    (* emptyEnv: 'a -> 'b *)
let emptyEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
let emptyFunEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
let emptyTuplaEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
    (*bind: ('a -> 'b) -> ide -> exp -> (ide -> exp ) *)
let bind env (variable: ide) value = fun y ->
            if variable = y then value else env y;;

    (*Funzioni di supporto*)
(*Casting da exp a tipi primitivi*)
let asint = function Int x -> x | _ -> failwith "not an integer";;
let asbool = function Bool x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a boolean";;
let aslist = function Lista x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a list";;
(*Cast da Lista_exp to Lista_elts *)
let aslist_e = function ListaE x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a list_e";;
let tupla2Lista = function Tupla(x, y) -> y | _ -> failwith "non a tupla";;

let rec getElement lista index = match lista with
    | [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
    | primo::elems -> if index = 0 then primo else getElement elems (index-1);;

let rec first lista number = if number = 0 then [] else
    let lista1 = aslist(lista) in
        match lista1 with
        | [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
        | primo::elems -> let resto = Lista(elems) in primo::(first resto (number-1));;

let rec map lista funct = match lista with
    | [] -> []
    | elem::elems -> (funct elem)::(map elems funct);;

let rec valTuple lista eval_fun env funenv tenv = match lista with
    | [] -> []
    | elem::elems -> (eval_fun elem env funenv tenv)::(valTuple elems eval_fun env funenv tenv);;

let funDeclr (expression: exp) env funenv = match expression with
    | Function (funName, param, body) -> bind funenv funName (param, body, env)
    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException;;

let tupleDeclr (tupla: exp) env tenv = match tupla with
    | Tupla (id, lista) -> bind tenv id lista
    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException;;

let append elemento lista2 = let lista21 = aslist (aslist_e lista2)
                                in elemento::lista21

let appendE elemExp elemExpLE = let listaE = aslist_e elemExpLE in
                                match listaE with
                                | Elemento (expr) -> Lista(elemExp::[expr])
                                | Lista (exprlist) -> Lista(elemExp::exprlist);;

let rec eval (expression: exp) env funenv tenv =
    match expression with
    | Int i -> Int(i)
    | Ide i -> env i
    | Bool i -> Bool(i)
    | Add (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) + asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Sub (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) - asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Mul (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) * asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Eq (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1 env funenv tenv) = (eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Leq (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1 env funenv tenv) <= (eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | And (e1, e2) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) && asbool(eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Or (e1, e2) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) || asbool(eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Not (e1) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) then Bool(false) else Bool(true)
    | FunApply (funName, arg) -> (*Chiamata di funzione*)
        let value = eval arg env funenv tenv in
                let (param, body, ambiente) = funenv funName in
                        let env1 = bind env param value in
                            eval body env1 funenv tenv
    | IfThenElse (e1, e2, e3) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) then eval e2 env funenv tenv
                                                                else eval e3 env funenv tenv
    | LetIn (id, value, body) -> let value = eval value env funenv tenv in
                                    let env1 = bind env id value in
                                        eval body env1 funenv tenv
    (*| Tupla (id, lista) -> let lista1 = aslist(lista) in
                            let lista0 = valTuple lista1 eval env funenv tenv in
                                    ListaE(Lista(lista0))*)
    | GetIndex (id, i) -> let index = asint(eval i env funenv tenv) in
                            let lista = aslist(id) in
                                getElement lista index
    | GetFirstN (exp, i) -> let index = asint(eval i env funenv tenv) in
                                ListaE(Lista(first exp index))
    | TupleEquals (exp1, exp2) -> if aslist(exp1) = aslist(exp2) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Map (funx, exp1) -> let lista = aslist(aslist_e(eval exp1 env funenv tenv)) in
                         let (param, body, ambiente) = funenv funx in
                        (match lista with
                          | [] -> ListaE(Lista([]))
                          | x::xs ->
                            let value = eval x env funenv tenv in
                                let env1 = bind env param value in
                                    let remaining = ListaE(Lista(xs)) in
                                        ListaE(appendE (eval body env1 funenv tenv)
                                                (eval (Map (funx,remaining)) env1 funenv tenv))
                        )

    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException
;;

(**TEST**)
let simpleAnd = And(Bool true, Bool true);;
let doubleAnd = And(Bool true, And( Bool true, Bool false));;
eval simpleAnd emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;
eval doubleAnd emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;

let letAndEquals = LetIn("x", Int 1, Eq(Ide "x", Int 1));;
eval letAndEquals emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;

let simpleAdd = LetIn("x", Int 2, LetIn("y", Int 4, Add(Ide "x", Ide "y")));;
eval simpleAdd emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;

(*Valutazione Tupla*)
let lista_x = Lista(Ide "x" :: Int(23) :: Add(Ide "x", Int 2) ::[]);;
let exampleList = LetIn("x", Int 2, Tupla("lista", lista_x));;

eval exampleList emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;

(*First 2 elems from tuple*)
let tupla = Tupla("tupla_x", Lista(Int (5) :: Int(6) :: Bool(true) :: Int(7) ::[]));;
let primi2 = GetFirstN(tupla2Lista(tupla), Int(2));;
eval primi2 emptyEnv emptyFunEnv emptyTuplaEnv;;

(*Map(raddoppia, tupla)*)
let raddoppia = Function("mul2", "x", Mul(Ide "x", Int 2));;
let funenv0 = funDeclr raddoppia emptyEnv emptyFunEnv;;
let tupla = Tupla("tupla_x", Lista(Int (5) :: Int(6) :: Bool(true) :: Int(7) ::[]));;
let lista = tupla2Lista(tupla);;
let exampleMap = Map("mul2", GetFirstN(lista, Int 2));;
eval exampleMap emptyEnv funenv0 emptyTuplaEnv;;

(*
let simpleFunction = LetIn("x", Int 14, FunApply("mul2", Ide "x"));;
eval simpleFunction emptyEnv funenv0;;

let lista_x = Tuple("lista_x", Lista(Int 4, Int 5, Int 6));;
let simpleMap = Map("mul2", Ide "lista_x");;
eval simpleMap emptyEnv funenv0;;

(**TEST DAL PDF**)
let add5 = Function("add5", "x", Add(Ide "x", Int 5));;
let funenv1 = funDeclr add5 emptyEnv emptyFunEnv;;

(*let tupla = Tupla(Int 5, Int 6, Bool true, Int 7);;
let test1 = LetIn("x", Int 5, LetIn("t", tupla, Map(GetFirstN(Ide "t", Int 2)), Function("x", Add(Ide "x", Int 5))));;
eval test1 emptyEnv funenv1;;*)

*)
```

I'm trying to build an interpreter. Given the following code, when I try to execute its, last line (eval exampleMap emptyEnv funenv0 emptyTuplaEnv;;) returns WrongMatchException. I think that problem is generated by Map, since primi2 use function GetFirstN without any problems.

I don't understand why Map isn't matched. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like that you fail on `eval exampleList`, since your `eval` pattern matching lacks `Lista` branch. That's why it is considered a bad practice to add a catch-all wildcard `_` case. If you remove it, then the compiler will tell you what branches you have forgotten.